# Python Project Set Up

Tags: python, installation

I am completing a work sample from Google as part of the Bright Network Experience and I am stuck at the very beginning.
I have just downloaded Python on my Mac and the work sample says the following:

***Running and testing from the Commandline***

To run the command-line application:

python3 -m src.run

You can close the app by typing EXIT as a command.

***Running the tests:***

To run all the tests:

python3 -m pytest

Can someone please explain what should I do with this information?

I tried running these on PyCharm but it just says that I don't have any files with that name.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!-- This is an HTML comment -->
```

```js
// This is a JS comment

/*
This is also a JS comment
But it can be multiline
*/
```